# As returning a response to a ajax symfony 2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a very simple system where ordinary users, the gold amounts to users. At first it had simply made ​​a path in the routing.yml I address the function to execute the action and return to the same view and worked perfectly. Now implement ajax to make the process faster .
when I click on the button up , run the Ajax , the specified path to the controller directs me to the relevant action, all successfully executed , but at the time of return to the same view , is not working. Ajax take the path of error , and was printed by an Alert screen programmed by me. In conclusion, everything works fine, until I have to return to Ajax action .

***listarUsuariosParaAscender.html.twig***

```
    //..some code..//
    <p id="{{ usuario.id }}" >Ascender a Usuario Gold</p>
    //..some code..//

    {% block javascripts %}
        {{ parent() }}
        <script type="text/javascript" src=" {{ asset('bundles/MICARPETA/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js') }} "></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(e) {

            $("p").click(function(e){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "{{ path('ascender_a_gold') }}",
                                data: { 'id' : ' ' + id + ' ' },
                                error: function(){
                                      alert("Error petición ajax");
                                },
                                success: function(data){                                                    

                                      alert(data);

                                }
                    });
            });
        });
        </script> 

{% endblock %}
```

***routing.yml***

```
ascender_a_gold:
    pattern: /admin/ascenderAGold
    defaults: { _controller: ProyectoAdminBundle:Admin:ascenderAGold }
```

***AdminController.php***

```
public function ascenderAGoldAction(){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = new User();
        $roleviejo = new Role();
        $rolenuevo = new Role();
        $usuario = $em->getRepository('AtajoBundle:User')->findOneUser($id);
        $roleviejo = $em->getRepository('ProyectoSeguridadBundle:Role')->findByRoleJoinUsuario($id);
        $rolenuevo = $em->getRepository('ProyectoSeguridadBundle:Role')->findByRole('ROLE_USER_GOLD');

        $usuario->setRoles($rolenuevo);

        $em->persist($usuario);
        $em->flush();

        //Until here everything works well , when I have to return to Ajax , ajax it takes the path of 'error'    

        $data = 'hello';

        return new JsonResponse(array('data' => $data)); 
        }
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see status and what is returned(if any). Also set `dataType:'json'` for `$.ajax

Comment: Why are you using `$_POST` instead of symfony's `Request` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the last two lines of your controller, so there shouldn't be an error. The only thing that could be missing is including the JsonResponse class. Have you got the following use statement at the top of your controller?

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
```